# In C# how can I create an IEnumerable<T> class with different types of objects>

Tags: c#, .net, object, collections, ienumerable

In C# how can I create an `IEnumerable<T>`class with different types of objects

For example:

```
Public class Animals
{

Public class dog{}

Public class cat{}

Public class sheep{}

}
```

I want to do some thing like:

```
Foreach(var animal in Animals)
{
Print animal.nameType
}
```

Comment: Implement `IEnumerable`, inherit from `ArrayList`, `CollectionBase`, `List<t>`, etc.

Comment: You might consider making `Animal` an `abstract` base class because there is nothing that is `Animal` without *also* being some more specific kind of animal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

another approach if you wanted a named collection (instead of using a a `List<T>`):

```
// animal classes
public class Animal
{
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public Animal() : this("Unknown") {}
    public Animal(String name) { this.Name = name; }
}
public class Dog : Animal
{
    public Dog() { this.Name = "Dog"; }
}
public class Cat : Animal
{
    public Cat() { this.Name = "Cat"; }
}

// animal collection
public class Animals : Collection<Animal>
{

}
```

Implementation:

```
void Main()
{
    // establish a list of animals and populate it
    Animals animals = new Animals();
    animals.Add(new Animal());
    animals.Add(new Dog());
    animals.Add(new Cat());
    animals.Add(new Animal("Cheetah"));

    // iterate over these animals
    foreach (var animal in animals)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(animal.Name);
    }
}
```

Here you extend off the foundation of [`Collection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132397.aspx) which implements `IEnumerable<T>` (so `foreach` and other iterating methods work from it).

Answer (score 15):

```
public class Animal {

}

public class Dog : Animal {

}

public class Cat : Animal {

}


List<Animal> animals = new List<Animal>();

animals.Add(new Dog());
animals.Add(new Cat());
```

You can then iterate over the collection via:

```
foreach (var animal in animals) {
    Console.WriteLine(animal.GetType());
}
```

Comment: @newStackExchangeInstance - yes it will.

Answer (score 1):

Create an Animal base class. Let each specific animal inherit from Animal. Create an abstract method in Animal called NameType, that each subclass overrides. Create a `List<Animal>` and iterate over that.